# Rename Instance API in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am looking for Softlayer APIs to rename the created VM and BareMetal instances.
Used Softlayer java-client-lib, the APIs should be called from cloud portal page we are developing.
It'll be helpful if you provide any sample or API guide regarding this API.

Thank you
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These examples may help you:

**Java example:**

**Edit Virtual Guest**

```
package virtualGuest;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest.Service;

public class editInstance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          String username = "set me";
            String apikey = "set me";
            ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apikey);

            Long vsiId = new Long(11498369);
            String newHostName = "vsi-test-JavaEdited";
            String myNote = "Editing from Java";


            Guest templateObject = new Guest();

            templateObject.setHostname(newHostName);
            templateObject.setNotes(myNote);

            Service vsiService = Guest.service(client, vsiId);

            try 
            {
                Boolean result = false; 
                result = vsiService.editObject(templateObject);
                System.out.println("The Virtual Instance Server was edited sucessfullly: " + result);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
    }

}
```

**Python Examples:**

**Edit Virtual Guest:**

```
"""
Edit details of a Virtual Guest.
It edits a computing instance's properties


Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/editObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
# For nice debug output:
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set me'

# Generate one at https://control.softlayer.com/account/users
API_KEY = 'set me'

serverId = 7437756

# Create an object template with data that you wish to edit.
# For example: I want to edit the "hostname" and "notes".
objectTemplate = {
    'hostname': 'myhostnameEdited',
    'notes': 'edited from api'
    }

client = SoftLayer.Client(
    username=API_USERNAME,
    api_key=API_KEY
)

try:
    # Edits an existing virtual Guest server
    # The expected result after executing the script is: true
    result = client['Virtual_Guest'].editObject(objectTemplate, id=serverId)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        pp('Unable to edit the virtual guest details faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
            % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

**Edit Bar Metal server:**

```
"""
Edit a bare metal server's basic information

Change the notes property for a single bare metal server record to the sentence "This
is my fastest server!" using the editObject() method in the
SoftLayer_Hardware_Server API service. See below for more details.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/editObject

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer


# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# The name of the server we wish to edit.
serverName = 'set me'

"""
Define the new local properties to set.

A SoftLayer_Hardware_Server record has a few local properties that you can
change via the API. Every service's editObject() method takes a single
parameter, a skeleton object that only defines the properties we wish to
change. While we're only editing a server's notes in this example you can
also use editObject() to edit the server's host name and domain record.
"""
editTemplate = {
    'notes': 'This is my fastest server!'
}

# The id of the bare metal you wish to edit
hardwareId = ''

# Declare a new API service object
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)


"""
Call the getHardware() method from the SoftLayer_Account API service to get
a list of hardware on your account, including id numbers.
"""
try:
    hardwareList = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getHardware()
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    error message.
    """
    print("Unable to retrieve bare metal list. "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))

# Looking for the server name to get its id
for hardware in hardwareList:
    if hardware['hostname'] == serverName:
        hardwareId = hardware['id']

# If the server name was not found we throw an error message.
if hardwareId == '':
    raise Exception("Unable to find the server with the name " + serverName)

try:
    # Edit our server record.
    result = client['SoftLayer_Hardware_Server'].editObject(editTemplate, id=hardwareId)
    print ('Bare Metal Server edited')
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to edit the bare metal server. "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

References:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/editObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/editObject

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the edit methods

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/editObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/editObject

here an example to change it for a VSI

```
package api.examples;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;

public class ChangeHostnameVSI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String user = "set me";
        String apikey = "set me";



        // The id of the VSI where you want to change the properties
        Long virtualGuestId = new Long(10476867);

        // Declare the API client.
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(user, apikey);
        Guest.Service virtualGuestService = Guest.service(client,
                virtualGuestId);

        try {
            Guest guest = new Guest();
            // Changing the properties
            guest.setHostname("mynewhostname");
            guest.setDomain("exampledomain.com");
            virtualGuestService.editObject(guest);

            System.out.println("The guest was edited. ");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Unable to edit the data. " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }


}
```